# MySQL Recursive query to find the shortest path

Tags: mysql, dijkstra, recursive-query

I have an issue I just can't get my head around...

I have a table called `country_neighbour` looking like this.

| Country_name | Country_id | Neighbour_name | Neighbour_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 1 | France | 2 |
| Italy | 1 | Switzerland | 6 |
| Italy | 1 | Austria | 5 |
| France | 2 | Spain | 3 |
| France | 2 | Italy | 1 |
| France | 2 | Switzerland | 6 |
| Spain | 3 | France | 2 |
| Spain | 3 | Portugal | 4 |
| Portugal | 4 | Spain | 3 |

What i want to get is the shortest path to get from one country to another
lets say that I want to know how many borders is needed to cross to get to Portugal From Italy.

(Italy -> France) 1

(Italy -> France -> Spain -> Portugal) 3

I have been looking for ideas and find WITH cte a good approach to my problem but its not supported by MySQL

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction. I appreciate all help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: This is called a hierarchical query in the jargon of the trade. MySQL doesn't support hierarchical queries directly, but there are plenty of resources on the internet describing workarounds.

Comment: @olliejones it's not called recursion?

Comment: Yeah, it's called recursion too. But this OQ needed some hints on where else to search, eh?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by first detecting the longest path, such that no same node occurs in the same path. After you get this numeric value, you can apply a sequence of several `SELF LEFT JOIN` operations by imposing two conditions:

- country-neighbour match: the neighbour name of the table t1 is equal to the country name of the table t2
- already seen node: the neighbour name of table t2 shall not be one of the previous country

Calculating the longest path will make you know how many `LEFT JOIN` you need to carry out to accomplish to this operation. Following there's a snippet given that the longest path is 4.

```
SELECT 
    r1.country_name         AS r1_start,
    r1.neighbour_name       AS r1_neigh,
    r2.neighbour_name       AS r2_neigh,
    r3.neighbour_name       AS r3_neigh,
    r4.neighbour_name       AS r4_neigh
FROM      routes r1
LEFT JOIN routes r2 
       ON     r2.country_name = r1.neighbour_name 
      AND     r2.neighbour_name NOT IN 
                (r1.country_name, r1.neighbour_name)
LEFT JOIN routes r3 
       ON     r3.country_name = r2.neighbour_name 
      AND     r3.neighbour_name NOT IN 
                (r1.country_name, r1.neighbour_name, r2.neighbour_name)
LEFT JOIN routes r4 
       ON     r4.country_name = r3.neighbour_name 
      AND     r4.neighbour_name NOT IN 
                (r1.country_name, r1.neighbour_name, r2.neighbour_name, r3.neighbour_name)
```

Once I run the query, I would store the result set inside a table (not recommended a view as this query can be quite expensive on big datasets, even though the conditions should release some weight from these joins): `CREATE TABLE country_paths AS SELECT ...`

Then, if I want to compute the paths for a specific country, I would query the generated table imposing a filter: `SELECT * FROM country_paths WHERE r1.start = 'Italy'`.

Here you can find a fiddle too: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCkSHBH82RcFp1UMdXcfMW/0.

Side note: if the longest path is a really big number, then it would be advisable to use a [`prepared statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) in combo with a cycle, like is done [here](https://thispointer.com/mysql-convert-rows-to-columns/).